# null date time difference is displayed in textview

Tags: android, datetime

In my app, I was calculating date time difference. On inserting a node in firebase, I save current time in which node is created. And in an adapter, I want to display the difference in a `cardview` in seconds minutes or days.
 Problem is that there is no compile time error in the adapter. But nothing is shown in textview.

This is my activity in which node is inserted in firebase

```
        addMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String currentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

            String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
            String desc = etDesc.getText().toString();
            String url = etUrl.getText().toString();
            String cst = etCast.getText().toString();
            savedData(title, desc, url,cst,currentDateTime);
}

    private void savedData(String title, String desc, String url,String cast,String time) {
    String key = updateId;
    if (updateId == null) {
        key = databaseReference.push().getKey();
    }

    uploadImage(selectedimg, key);
    Movie movie = new Movie(title, desc, url, key,cast,time);
    Toast.makeText(this, "movie "+movie.getCast(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    movieReference.child(key).setValue(movie);
    etTitle.setText("");
    etDesc.setText("");
    etUrl.setText("");
    movieImage.setImageResource(0);
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

And This is my Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Movie> movies;
movieItemListener listener;
Context context;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
DecimalFormat df;


public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    this.movies = movies;
}

public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Movie> movies, movieItemListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movies = movies;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_layout, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    final Movie movie = movies.get(position);

    String currentTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    final String saveTime = movie.getCurrentDateTime();

    Toast.makeText(context, "abc"+getTimeDiff(currentTime, saveTime), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    holder.tvDate.setText(getTimeDiff(currentTime, saveTime));

    holder.tvRatings.setText(df.format(movie.getAvgRating()));

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("movies");

    databaseReference.child(movie.getId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            holder.tvRatings.setText(df.format(dataSnapshot.child("avgRating").getValue()));
            holder.tvViews.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("viewsCount").getValue()) + " Views");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    holder.tvTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow, position, movie);
        }
    });
}

private String getTimeDiff(String currentTime, String saveTime) {
    String diff="";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(currentTime);
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(saveTime);

        diff= printDifference(date1, date2);
        Toast.makeText(context, "in diff ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  return diff;
}


public String printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate) {

    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    String days=String.valueOf(elapsedDays);
    String hours=String.valueOf(elapsedHours);
    String minutes=String.valueOf(elapsedMinutes);
    String seconds=String.valueOf(elapsedSeconds);

 /*  if(elapsedSeconds>59)
       return minutes;
    else if(elapsedMinutes>59)
        return hours;
    else if(elapsedHours>24)
        return days;
    else*/
        return seconds;
}


private void showPopupMenu(View view, final int position, final Movie movie) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.movie_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_edit:
                    listener.onUpdate(movie);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_delete:
                    listener.onDelete(movie, position);
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}
}
```

I have been searching for a long time but failed to find the solution.
Does Anyone have an idea what I did wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong patterns, which is causing an exception and `diff` will be returned as empty sting, so you can use

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    try {
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(currentTime);
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(saveTime);
```

even for better solution, use

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();    
    try {
        Date date1 = df.parse(currentTime);
        Date date2 = df.parse(saveTime);
```

Comment: Your second solution gives error on  Date date2 = df.parse(saveTime); null object reference

Comment: and what is that error?, `null object reference` where ?

Comment: No,that was my mistake.it is not giving error.but return 0 diff.

Comment: in firebase node, this type of time is stored "Mar 4, 2018 6:55:42 PM"

Comment: it would be great if you can try some debugging and see the values of `endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()`

Comment: Now it works.I just changed your this line of code                     
 DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();    with this                              DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

Comment: @Numrah i am glad that i could help and thanks for the information , i somehow messed up the method names, nice work

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand completely but hope so this might work
in your node,save current date as

```
long currentDateTime=new Date().getTime();
```

and then in you getTimeDifference method

```
private String getTimeDifference(){
   long difference=new Date().getTime()-movie.getCurrentDateTime();
   DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
   return formatter.format(new Date(difference));
}
```

Comment: pay attention `String saveTime = movie.getCurrentDateTime();`, it's `String` not `long`

Comment: I've asked her to save time in long and not in string as "long currentDateTime=new Date().getTime();" then there is no need to first convert time into string then convert it back into date and long and then again into string ..